# How to get last "particular (Ex. March)" month in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to display the last March month. I am using the following code,

```
 date("Y-m-d",strtotime("last March"));
```

Any suggestions or references would be very helpful.

Comment: no it is giving me output as "1970-01-01".........

Comment: is the date on your server correct

Comment: "last March" isn't defined under [Relative Formats](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: yes, i am getting the correct output of "date("Y-m-d",strtotime("last Monday"));" but in the case of month it is not working..

Comment: last March is.. March? Are you trying to get the last day of the last march or what? I don't see any sense in getting date of `last March`, however `last Monday` makes perfect sense as you are getting a date in which the last Monday falls on.

Comment: I want to display the records from last "March" to "June". I mean the records of last year falls in the months between March to June. are you getting?

Comment: @Heer That just made it more confusing for me. Do you want the March of last year? Or the last March that occurred?

Comment: As @NiftyDude said, please clarify what it is about March you need to know (1st? 31st? what if we're currently in March?), because otherwise I see this as being as simple as `$lastMarch = (date('n') <= 3 ? date('Y') - 1 : date('Y')) . '-03-01';`

Comment: I want the  March of last year.

Comment: Okay then, `$marchLastYear = (date('Y') - 1) . '-03-01';` Is that all you're looking for?

Comment: ohhh yes, now i got the answer i was needed. Thnk you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$year = date('Y');
if (date('n') < 3) {
    $year--;
}

$beginningOfLastMarch = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 1, $year);
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://php.net/date

```
date('M')
```

or

```
date('n')
```

or

```
date('m')
```

or, if you have a date

```
$mydate = "2010-05-12 13:57:01";
```

you can get like this

```
$month = date("m",strtotime($mydate));
```

m Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros 01 through 12

n Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros 1 through 12

Comment: The question appears to be asking how to generate relative months.

Comment: he can get lik this also $dtA = new DateTime();
     $date = $dtA->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");
     $newDate = strtotime('-1 month',strtotime($date));

Comment: It is useful but it is giving the output as Current month.

Comment: try this man by echo date("m",$newDate); from that previous code continue... this giving output correctly..

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do this but left my old solution at the bottom, as it may still be relevant for some people in certain use cases.

I found a better solution to my problem which involves prepending a date to `strtotime`, and then using the relative selectors. Say I wanted to select the `4th of March last year`. I just do:

```
strtotime('{THIS_YEAR}-03-04 last year');
```

Obviously, before processing this string, I would replace `{THIS_YEAR}` with `date('Y')`. This works, simply because I hard code the values I want. `03-04` as `4th of March`. I can replace these numbers with any date I like.

## Old Solution

---

I figured out a solution that worked for me and it doesn't really involve writing any complex algorithms or anything. It does involve slightly extending the syntax of `strtotime` though.

Even though PHP's `strtotime` isn't perfect (for all use cases), I found that if you join `strtotime`'s together, then you can make it extremely powerful.

Say if I wanted to select the `4th of last month`, I can't really do that... `strtotime` doesn't really accept ordinals. I.E `4th`.

However,  I can do `first day of last month`, which is pretty close. All I need is to change the day.

`strtotime` allows a `time()` to be  passed as a second argument. This means you can chain `strtotime`'s like so:

```
$time = time();
$time = strtotime('first day of last month', $time);
$time = strtotime('+3 days', $time);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $time);

// I know we don't really need the initial `$time = time()`. It is there for clarity
```

which will give us the right time: `4th of last month`.

This is where a little syntactic sugar comes in...

We can write a function that accepts partial `strtotime` strings separated by a delimeter:

```
function my_strtotime($str, $time = null, $delim = '|'){
    $time = ($time==null ? time() : $time);
    foreach(explode($delim, $str) as $cmd){
        $time = strtotime($cmd, $time);
    }
    return $time;
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
$str = 'first day of last month | +3 days';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', my_strtotime($str));
```

And there we have it. `4th of last month`.

There is no need to strip whitespace from the `explode` call, because `strtotime` already handles extra whitespace.

This can handle complex intervals like `last year | first day of March | +9 days | 14:00` which will always return `10th of March at 2pm last year`.

The best thing about this is that strings like `last year | first day of March | +9 days | 14:00` can be generated with the required values, E.G.

```
last year | first day of {MONTH} | +{DAYS-1} days | {TIME}
```

This might need extra work to improve it, but I just wanted to quickly get this out here, so it may help others reaching this question